# Is there a windows utility to scale windows on the screen?

Tags: windows, software-rec

I use an old VMWare Server and Citrix/RDP connections to connect to lots and lots of client's networks and routinely come upon clients who have strange desktop resolutions which I cannot change, leaving all kinds of annoying scroll bars - or worse, no scroll bars.

But, I also use gotoassist which does a nice job of shrinking down the main window to view it all on one screen.

I was just wondering if some hardy chap has designed a program to scale windows on the fly, so that, instead of moving and scrolling I could just view the whole thing on my own terms.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like [Zoomit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897434.aspx).  There's also the Windows & plus key zoom in WIn 7

Comment: Nope, exactly the opposite, I want to make windows shrink so I can see their entire contents when they would normally fill up my entire screen.   But that is really cool, especially the pen thing.

Comment: @uSlackr Thanks for the tip! That's a great tool to have. However, I understand the situation that the author is describing here, and I too would appreciate that kind of program. Something that can scale and zoom out, beyond the standard zoom level.